# How to open .pvd file in Paraview with visible content?

Tags: paraview

I've got a .pvd file that I want to open in paraview (ver 5.1.2). I want to do this from within the python script so my python code is like:

```
os.system('paraview '+filename)
```

The problem is that, by default in paraview, the object from .pvd file is not visible in render window. I've got to click on the "eyeball" icon in pipeline browser to see my plot. Is there any way (command line parameter for paraview or via some python's interface) to open a file with its content set to visible, avoiding additional mouse clicking?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use AutoApply:

Open ParaView -> Edit -> Settings -> AutoApply -> Close ParaView